# Rebalancing the Orc Brutes in Thunderspire labyrinth?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters, balance

The Orc Beserker is a miserably designed sack of hitpoints:

> Orc Berserker
>
> HP 66; Bloodied 33
>
> AC 15; Fortitude 17, Reflex 13, Will 12
>
> Speed 6 (8 while charging)
>
> Greataxe (standard, at-will)  Weapon
>
> +8 vs AC; 1d12+5 damage (crit 1d12+17).
>
> Warrior's Surge (standard; usable only while bloodied, encounter)  Healing, Weapon
>
> The orc berserker makes a melee basic attack, spends a healing surge, and regains 16 hit points.

Calculating in their warrior's surge (which is a horrible mechanic), they have: 66+16 = 82 HP versus the expected 56 HP or so.

Also, their absurd crit damage is... absurd.

What are some recommended balance modifications to this horrible creature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the Orcs in the *Monster Vault*.  Let's take the [brute](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/monster.aspx?id=5089) from there and downlevel it to match the Orc Berserker.

```
Orc Rampager
Medium natural humanoid

Level 4 Brute
XP 175
HP 68; Bloodied 34  Initiative +5
AC 16, Fortitude 18, Reflex 16, Will 14 Perception+3
Speed 6 Low-light vision

Traits
Berserk Flailing
While the orc is bloodied and can take opportunity actions, any enemy that 
starts its turn adjacent to the orc takes 5 damage.

Standard Actions
 Heavy Flail (weapon)  At-Will
Attack: Melee 1 (one creature); +9 vs. AC
Hit: 2d6 + 4 damage.
 Rampage  At-Will
Effect: The orc shifts up to 3 squares and can use heavy flail 
against three enemies during the shift.

 Handaxe (weapon)  At-Will
Attack: Ranged 10 (one creature); +9 vs. AC
Hit: 2d6 + 4 damage, and the orc can push the target 1 square.

Triggered Actions
Savage Demise  Encounter
Trigger: The orc drops to 0 hit points.
Effect (Free Action): The orc takes a standard action.
Str 21 (+8)                Dex 14 (+5)                Wis 10 (+3)
Con 20 (+8)                Int 8 (+2)                Cha 8 (+2)
Alignment chaotic evil        Languages Common, Giant
Equipment: handaxe x4, heavy flail , leather armor .
```

Now, this guy looks like a brute!  (And not like a big sack-o-hit points)

The Orc Savage <sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/monster.aspx?id=5085)</sup> is a nice L4 brute minion.  Make sure to mix some of those in as well.  Orcs should always come in a horde after all :)

Comment: or, possibly, in a horde.

Comment: @adriano - what?

Comment: triple attack at 2d6? owww?

Comment: @Brian - don't forget it's just a standard action.  It makes for a heck of a dying present to lay on the party :)  On the other hand, make sure the attacks go to 3 different characters.  He can't wail on the defender 3x a round.

Comment: @Brian: to be honest, 4e's orcs are pretty tame compared to 3e's orcs, especially if you consider the differences in damage and hit points. A single crit from a 3.0 CR 1/2 orc at 3d12+18 could auto-kill pretty much any *tough* character up to level 3. ;)

Comment: That doesn't make any difference whatsoever. The MM1 orcs are horribly designed. It's not that they're deadly. They're *boring*. Also, bringing up 3.5 is completely irrelevant to 4e.

Comment: @Brian: that was in response to your "owww". ;) The days where a single hit can auto-kill a character are luckily gone - at least in D&D. I am aware that there are certain design issues with MM1/2 (*cough*solos*cough*) but I don't think that the MM1 orcs are that bad.